# Filter and display database audit / changelog (activity stream)

Tags: postgresql, database-design, indexing, sqlalchemy

I'm developing an application with SQLAlchemy and PostgreSQL. Users of the system modify data in 8 or so tables. Consider this contrived example schema:

[image]

I want to add **visible logging** to the system to record what has changed, but not necessarily how it has changed. For example: "User A modified product Foo", "User A added user B" or "User C purchased product Bar". So basically I want to store:

1. Who made the change
2. A message describing the change
3. Enough information to reference the object that changed, e.g. the `product_id` and `customer_id` when an order is placed, so the user can click through to that entity

I want to show each user a list of *recent and relevant* changes when they log in to the application (a bit like the main timeline in Facebook etc). And I want to store subscriptions, so that users can subscribe to changes, e.g. "tell me when product X is modified", or "tell me when any products in store S are modified".

I have seen the [audit trigger recipe](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger_91plus), but I'm not sure it's what I want. That audit trigger might do a good job of *recording* changes, but how can I quickly filter it to show recent, relevant changes to the user? Options that I'm considering:

- Have one column per ID type in the log and subscription tables, with an index on each column
- Use full text search, combining the ID types as a [tsvector](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-textsearch.html)
- Use an hstore or json column  for the IDs, and index the contents somehow
- Store references as URIs (strings) without an index, and walk over the logs in reverse date order, using application logic to filter by URI

Any insights appreciated :)

**Edit** It seems what I'm talking about it an [activity stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214955/delivering-activity-feed-items-in-a-moderately-scalable-way). The suggestion in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2307874/320036) to filter by time first is sounding pretty good.

Comment: Pavel's solution directly shows the changes that were made to the data in a hstore column: http://okbob.blogspot.co.uk/2015/01/most-simply-implementation-of-history.html

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't address filtering by relevance. Is there a trick for indexing an hstore in a flexible way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the objects all use `uuid` for the `id` field, I think I'll create the activity table like this:

- Have a generic reference to the target object, with a `uuid` column with no foreign key, and an `enum` column specifying the type of object it refers to.
- Have an array column that stores generic `uuid`s (maybe as `text[]`) of the target object and its parents (e.g. parent categories, store and organisation), and search the array for marching subscriptions. That way a subscription for a parent category can match a child in one step (denormalised).
- Put a [btree](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/indexes-types.html) index on the date column, and (maybe) a GIN index on the array UUID column.

[image: Entity diagram of activity and subscription tables]

I'll probably filter by time first to reduce the amount of searching required. Later, if needed, I'll look at using [GIN](http://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/exploring-postgres-gin-index) to index the array column (this partially answers my question "*Is there a trick for indexing an hstore in a flexible way?*")

**Update** this is working well. The SQL to fetch a timeline looks something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (activity.created, activity.id)
        *
    FROM activity
        LEFT OUTER JOIN unnest(activity.object_ref) WITH ORDINALITY AS act_ref
            ON true
        LEFT OUTER JOIN subscription
            ON subscription.object_id = act_ref.act_ref
    WHERE activity.created BETWEEN :lower_date AND :upper_date
        AND subscription.user_id = :user_id
    ORDER BY activity.created DESC,
        activity.id,
        act_ref.ordinality DESC
) AS sub 
    WHERE sub.subscribed = true;
```

Joining with `unnest(...) WITH ORDINALITY`, ordering by ordinality, and selecting distinct on the activity ID filters out activities that have been *un*subscribed from at a deeper level. If you don't need to do that, then you could avoid the `unnest` and just use the array containment `@>` operator, and no subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM activity
    JOIN subscription ON activity.object_ref @> subscription.object_id
WHERE subscription.user_id = :user_id
    AND activity.created BETWEEN :lower_date AND :upper_date
ORDER BY activity.created DESC;
```

You could also join with the other object tables to get the object titles - but instead, I decided to add a `title` column to the `activity` table. This is denormalised, but it doesn't require a complex join with many tables, and it tolerates objects being deleted (which might be the action that triggered the activity logging).

Comment: Do you left-join using the generic reference to the target object through the UUID?

Comment: @JohnSmith No, I added a `title` column to the activity table instead. Fetching target objects is done at the application level, when the user clicks on an activity in their timeline. See my edit.

Comment: Do you print out the formatted strings, using predefined verbs from an array?

Comment: How does your timeline of activities look?